# unrecognized tag prefix or device filter'asp'

Tags: asp.net

As I was starting my project in Visual Studio Community 2015, I always ended up in seeing an error which says, `"Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'"` in all of the tools that I drag and drop on my project. Any help and solution are very much appreciated. This is the screenshot of the error in

[image: Visual Studio Community 2015].